# How to monitor and alert on changes made to Azure Storage Account Firewall rules

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-keyvault, azure-monitoring

I'm looking to monitor(obtain ip addresses and alert on) changes made to Firewall rules in azure storage account(also Key Vaults). I'm checking the Activity Log but the log I mostly see is
"Create or Update Storage Account" log for any changes(even for the changes made to firewall rules) in Activity Log.

Following is the place where I'm adding the firewall rules Storage Account --> Networking --> Firewall Rules

[image]

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment

You can view the changes made to Azure Storage Account Firewall rules from the Activity Log.

In the Activity Log, the storage account firewall rules logs are seen under Operation Name **Write StorageAccounts**

[image]

Comment: unfortunately i don't see Write StorageAccounts operation in my environment. And, I'm looking to obtain more detail like what new ip address is added/removed